# How does FluentWait actually see an element that will be uploaded?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing a program in which I use FluentWait to search for an element that will be uploaded to the webpage after a certain amount of time. I then need the program to click on the element and work from there. My question is, if the page isn't being refreshed every so often, how would this work? I understand that it polls the site with a specific time setting but if the browser isn't reloading the page how can it actually find the new element?

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait(driver)
        .withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement refresher = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
        {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) 
            {
                return driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link Text of Item"));            
            }
        });

        String productlink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link Text of Item")).getAttribute("href");
        driver.get(productlink);
```

This is my attempt using the while loop to refresh the browser until it finds the element (in this case a product added by the website)

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Supreme®/ANTIHERO® Ppe Crewneck")).size() > 0;
        while(!isPresent){
            driver.get(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    }
```

I'm new to Selenium and any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser isn't refreshing the page, or if there isn't some javascript that's updating the content of the page, then FluentWait won't find the element you are looking for.  FluentWait is really only helpful if your test takes an action that will cause the page to refresh, or some javascript to update the content, revealing the target element.  The objective of the FluentWait is to wait long enough for the refresh/update to complete before it clicks the element.

Comment: Thank you @Breaks Software . Do you know which way I would have to proceed in order to refresh the browser until the element is found?

Comment: No.  It would be a matter of how your web application functions.  What does a user do that ultimately causes the element to become visible?  that is the action your script needs to take.

Comment: This is a bot that is supposed to refresh/scan the website a minute or two early until a specific item is released. The user isn't in control of the element becoming visible (in this case)

Comment: I'm still not clear if the browser page is automatically refreshed by some bot,  so the user does not have to interact with the browser, or would a user typically just keep pressing the browser refresh button to see the element  become visible after this bot has done it's job?

Comment: Without the bot the user would keep refreshing the page (let's say starting at 10:59) until somewhere around 11 when the item would be released. Ideally the bot would refresh the browser searching for the newly added item. Currently, my program only works for already loaded items.

Comment: Ah! You did say that, this code is FOR the BOT.  sorry.  So, try using driver.navigate().refresh(); somewhere in there to tell the browser to refresh.

Comment: No worries! And thanks. I tried using driver.navigate ().refresh () in a while loop that searches for the element (while not found -> refresh) however it only refreshes once.

Comment: If you update your code above to show your current code, maybe we can comment on the wait and loop.

Comment: isPresent is never updated within the while loop.  It's just set once before the loop.